# AngularJS update model/view on POST http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this - I'm new to AngularJS and struggling with data binding. I've done some simple examples with local models and controllers but am now trying to expand to using a REST service and splitting out services from the controller. I feel like I should be updating my model $forecastData variable at the end of the create so this gets bound back to the screen, but I can't access from the service. The data is created successfully from the post and if I refresh the browser the data appears correctly - I just want this screen update to happen automatically as it should.

My screen is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MeterApp">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>     
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/v1.0.4/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-controller="ForecastFormController"  ng-init="getData()">
        <div class="panel-heading">Forecast Data</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Forecast Date</th>
                <th>Value (kWh)</th>
            <tr ng-repeat="forecast in forecastData"">
              <td>{{forecast.forecast_date}}</td>
              <td>{{forecast.value_kwh}}</td>
            </tr>  
            </table>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary  col-lg-4" ng-controller="ForecastFormController">
        <div class="panel-heading">Add Forecast</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="forecast-date">Forecast Date:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="forecast-date" ng-model="forecast.forecast_date">
                    <br>
                    <label for="forecast-value">Forecast Value (KwH):</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="forecast-value" ng-model="forecast.value_kwh">
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="create()">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Services/controller are:

```
app.service('forecastDataService', function($http) {

    this.getData = function() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:51437/api/forecasts'
         });
    }

    this.addData = function(f){
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:51437/api/forecasts',
        });
    }   
});

app.controller('ForecastFormController', function($scope, forecastDataService) {

    /*  $scope.forecastData = [ {"id":1,"value_kwh":1000.0,"forecast_date":"2015-11-27T00:00:00"},{"id":2,"value_kwh":1000.0,"forecast_date":"2015-11-28T00:00:00"},{"id":4,"value_kwh":1000.0,"forecast_date":"2015-11-29T00:00:00"}]; */

    $scope.forecastData = null;
    $scope.foreast = {};

    $scope.getData = function(){
        forecastDataService.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.forecastData = dataResponse.data;
            console.dir($scope.forecastData);
            return $scope.forecastData;
        });                     
    }

    $scope.create = function(){    
        console.dir("Called create method with: " + $scope.forecast.value_kwh + ":" + $scope.forecast.forecast_date);
        forecastDataService.addData($scope.forecast).then(function(dataResponse) {
                        console.dir("Success - data response: " + dataResponse.data);
                        });     
    }   
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for the above answer. After looking at the angular js up and running book the obvious (most simple way seemed to be to refactor as follows):

Service:

```
    app.service('forecastService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return{
        get: function(){
            return $http.get('http://localhost:51437/api/forecasts');
            },
        create: function(data){
            return $http.post('http://localhost:51437/api/forecasts', data)
            }
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ForecastController', ['forecastService', function(forecastService) {

    /*  $scope.forecastData = [ {"id":1,"value_kwh":1000.0,"forecast_date":"2015-11-27T00:00:00"},{"id":2,"value_kwh":1000.0,"forecast_date":"2015-11-28T00:00:00"},{"id":4,"value_kwh":1000.0,"forecast_date":"2015-11-29T00:00:00"}]; */

    var self = this
    self.forecastData = [];
    self.newForecast = {};

    var getData = function(){
        return forecastService.get().then(
            function(response){
                self.forecastData  = response.data;
            }, function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while fetching data: ');
                console.error(errResponse);
            });
    };

    getData();

    self.create = function(){    
        forecastService.create(self.newForecast)
            .then(getData)
            .then(function(response){
                self.newForecast = {};
            }); 
    };  
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a object from service and when you want to refresh data, simply call refresh function like:

```
app.service('forecastDataService', function($http) {
    var data = {
         forecast: {}
    };
    this.getData = function() {
        return data;
    }

    this.refreshData = function(f){
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:51437/api/forecasts',
        }).then(unction(dataResponse) {
           data.forecast = dataResponse.data;
        });
    }   
});
```

Use the service in controller:

```
$scope.forecastData = forecastDataService.getData();
```

Getting newest data from server and update to view

```
forecastDataService.refreshData();
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks sensible, I'll just have to rewrite the code and will confirm it works